# Dynamic text resets instead of retaining current value with multiple buttons AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having trouble with this: 
http://josimar.com/StackOverflow_AS3_spumker_Question.swf

Here's a .zip of the Flash file:
http://josimar.com/StackOverflow_AS3_spumker_Question.fla.zip

I need the 'counter' dynamic text (based on timeline) to show a cumulative total when either of the A or B buttons are clicked.

Currently, buttons A & B are in a movieclip and A takes up the first 50 frames of the clip, then B the next 50.

You'll notice if you access the .swf example, if you immediately click A a few times, then click B when it becomes clickable, the dynamic text does as desired and 'adds' to the total.

However, when the movie clip holding those buttons gets to frame 100, I just let it run back to frame 1 and then, when you click on A again or B again, it resets the total to 1. This is the problem, I need the total to remain wherever it got to, not reset!?

Code in button_container: ('clicked' is the dynamic text name on main timeline)

```
var clickCount:int = 0;

button_A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick);

function addClick(event:MouseEvent):void {

  clickCount++;
  Object(root).clicked.text = clickCount.toString();

  }
```

Also, I'd ideally like to have all AS3 on the main timeline somehow. Is this advisable or even the best way to do it? Reason being, e.g. I would eventually like to have 25 x separate 'button_containers' ALL with identical A & B buttons within them and would need to be able to target them all from the main timeline with AS3 and they would again ADD to the 'clicked' total, never resetting it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have spent a long time trying to suss this out and searching this site for solutions with no luck.

ta
spumker

The following is an example of my attempt at controlling the buttons from the main timeline: (mcone/mctwo/mcthree are necessary movieclips btw, I need to keep to this structure :)

```
var clickCount:int = 0;


Object(root).mcone.mctwo.buttonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick2);

function addClick2(event:MouseEvent):void {

  clickCount++;
  Object(root).mcthree.clicked.text = clickCount.toString();


}
```

Comment: `var clickCount:int = 0;` sets the variable to `0` when you visit that frame and you do visit that frame. What's the purpose of the 50 frames with A and 50 frames with B? Is that to control how long each of them is visible?

Comment: The 50 frames per button is just to allow me to show A, then B separately. It's a game I'm working on which requires the player being only allowed to click on particular buttons at particular points of that 'button_container' movie clip timeline... 

It probably makes more sense in this code example below - take a look at this... my as3 (all on main timeline) attempt to control everything from root level - see * at foot of main question.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, sorry, I see what you are saying btw re: the variable is hitting that frame and resetting. Ok, so, basically I only want to have that line:

var clickCount:int = 0;

.... at the very start (somehow)?

Comment: I added a gotoAndPlay(2); to the button_container clip and after also moving the button AS3 and 'A' button mc along one frame it DOES NOT RESET the 'clicked' dynamic text when I continually press A/B/A/B etc! Thanks null :) 
I'll now give it a shot with all AS3 on main timeline in my game.fla... fingers crossed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be much better off moving all the code off the timeline and using classes. If this isn't something you're comfortable with you should consider keeping the code on the first keyframe only.

Heres an example of what you could do if you put the code all on the first frame:

```
var clickCount:int = 0;
var frameCount:int = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    frameCount ++;

    if (frameCount <= 50) {
        button_A.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick);
        button_B.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick);
    } else if (frameCount <= 100) {
        button_A.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick);
        button_B.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick);
    } else {
        frameCount = 0;
    }
}

function addClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    clickCount++;
    counter_txt.text = String(clickCount);
}
```

**EDIT:** I've uploaded the fixed project to: http://www.anthonybirch.org/stackoverflow/StackOverflow_AS3_spumker_Question_4.fla

You were very close ... your problem is that inside each of your MovieClips for buttons A/B and C/D you are creating another instance of clickCount. I can see you are doing this because as you could not access clickCount directly from inside your MovieClips. By putting `Object(root).` (which you already worked out for the textfield) in front of clickCount this allows you the access needed.

Please mark this question as correct if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks AntBirch. Had a little look at a few class tutorials on youtube, very neat and interesting. For now, however, I'll stick with my code within my game .fla! I've updated the .fla and .swf files and put them here: 
http://josimar.com/StackOverflow_AS3_spumker_Question_V2.fla.zip 
http://josimar.com/StackOverflow_AS3_spumker_Question_V2.swf 
The problem remains of the 4 clickable buttons NOT adding to the total in the counter and it resets due to the presence of the 'var clickCount:int = 0' code at frame 1. ps the .fla is a replica of my game structure so I need to stick to it.

Comment: Defiantly worth looking into for the future :) you could always initiate 'var clickCount:int = 0;' on frame 1 and then use gotoAndStop(2); when your animation reached frame 101. This approach would mean you'd only have to add another frame in front of your current 2. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again AntBirch, I've tried that approach and while within that MovieClip it stops the counter resetting, when I then access the counter (add to it) from other MovieClips I need to declare the var within those Movieclips too or it won't work and therefore it resets again to 0. Excuse my non-technical approach but is there a way of saying (within all MovieClips), instead of: var clickCount:int = 0; it just gets the global current value? e.g. var clickCount:int = (current value);

Comment: I've downloaded your project and made the necessary fixes for this to work. Please see my answer as it has been updated.

Comment: Oh wow, I'll take a look - thanks so much! I was actually preparing my game project .fla and going to ask you if you'd take a peek but hopefully no need :) Thanks so much guys!

Comment: Oh, just reading your answer above makes total sense - I had asked the same thing myself about adding a prefix to clickCount to target it like I would a movie clip BUT as it wasn't targetable/visible (like other instances/MovieClips) in the 'Insert target Path' window... I assumed that wasn't the way to do it! Cheers, I'll dig into your version of my .fla right now.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please be sure to mark as correct answer if that answers your question so others know this question is answered.

Comment: YUSSSS, got it working as required now thanks to AntBirch and null too!!! Very much appreciated.